# DB connection getting closed while inserting record by MDB

Tags: ibm-was

I have created MDB to pick the message from MQ and inserting in to DB2.
I have created data sourse to get the DB connection in WAS. Its inserting message. But due to the speed of the MessageListener some messages not inserted because the connection got closed.. 
Please help me to handle the conction here..

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(
                propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"), @ActivationConfigProperty(
                propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/MDBQueue")
        }, 
        mappedName = "jms/MDBQueue")
public class AsyncMessageConsumerBean implements MessageListener {
     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    private javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = null;
    private javax.sql.DataSource serviceDataSource = null;
    private String environment = null;

    /**
     * @see MessageListener#onMessage(Message)
     */

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("On Message Started.....");

    try{
        if (message instanceof javax.jms.BytesMessage)
        {
            javax.jms.BytesMessage bytesMessage = (javax.jms.BytesMessage) message;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) bytesMessage.getBodyLength()];

            bytesMessage.readBytes(bytes);
            System.out.println("Reply Message");

            String replyMessage = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(" The message received from MQ :-----" + replyMessage);

            insertMQMessage(replyMessage);

        }else {

            javax.jms.TextMessage TextMessage = (javax.jms.TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("----------- The text message received from UM Queue"+TextMessage.getText());

            insertMQMessage(TextMessage.getText());

        }

        }catch (JMSException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

}
public void insertMQMessage(String mqMessage) throws Exception
{

            Statement stmtsql = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    try 
    {
        connection = getDBConnection();
        System.out.println("Connection Object :"+connection);

        String mqMsgTrackerInsertQry = "";

        System.out.println("MQ Tracker insert Query:" + mqMsgTrackerInsertQry);

        stmtsql = connection.createStatement();
        boolean status  = stmtsql.execute(mqMsgTrackerInsertQry);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    finally 
    {

        if (stmtsql != null)
            try {
                stmtsql.close();
            } catch (SQLException ignore) {
            }
        if (connection != null)
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ignore) {
            }
    }    

}


private Connection getDBConnection() throws SQLException {

             try {
                ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
                serviceDataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/DB_DS_XA");
                System.out.println("Datasource initiallised"+serviceDataSource);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                System.out.println("peformanceappraisalstatus: COULDN'T CREATE CONNECTION!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             Connection connection = null;
            try {
                 connection = serviceDataSource.getConnection();
                //connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw e;
            }

            return connection;
        }
}
```

Comment: Make a `connection` local variable in the  `insertMQMessage()` method, not a class field. And your `getDBConnection()` should return connection, not void. You should also remove `setAutoCommit`.

Comment: did the changes..But still facing the same issue..

Comment: Update your code in the question as it is hard to tell, how you made these changes. The best would be to add your whole MDB code, not just pieces.

Comment: I have posted the entire MDB class

Comment: At first look, it should work fine now. If you still observe strange behavior ensure you dont have any exceptions in the `SystemOut.log`. Make sure you reinstalled the app.